# How can I select all table's rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I need to get all rows of the table. Currently I do that like this:

```
$all_rows = TBname::where('id', '>', '0')->get();
```

As you see, I've used `id > 0` condition to select all rows. But I think this isn't a standard way. In pure SQL I can use `. . . where 1`. But in Laravel `where('1')` doesn't work.

Anyway, what's the most standard approach to select *(and fetch)* all rows in Laravel?

Comment: If you want to retrieve all the rows of a table simple use 
TBname::get();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `all()`:

```
TBname::all();
```

Or `get()`:

```
TBname::get();
```

Comment: thank you .. upvote .. can you please also tell me how can I do that when I use `DB` fecade? `DB::table('TBname')` ?

Comment: Use this `DB::table('TBname')->get()`

Answer (score 1):

With `->all()`

```
$all_rows = TBname::all();
```

More information in [Eloquent Retrieving Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#retrieving-models)